# Float math issue storing crypto values

Tags: database, floating-point, sqldatatypes

**The Problem**

I recently started working on a small backend application to track my staking rewards and I stumbled upon the floating point math issues for the first time in my life.

After some research two options seem to be preferred in general:

- **DECIMAL(27,18)**: Very useful for ETH tokens (which mostly have 18 decimals).
- **BIGINT**: Useful but I think it will run out of space for tokens like Shiba Inu.

**The Question(s)**

- If I store the tokens as DECIMAL, will I have to perform the operations in the database to avoid the floating point math issue?
- Would it be a better approach to store everything as int and then divide by the token's decimal digits, stored separatedly? (Maybe something like: NUMERIC(72,0)?)
- Is there a third option or other problems I'm not taking into account?

Comment: Do you need very large and very small numbers, like 10^100 and 10^−100? That is what floating-point is for. If you do not need a large range of numbers, avoid using floating-point. What is an ETH token? Is it just a sequence of digits? Is it a hexadecimal string? Do you do arithmetic on it? If you need to do arithmetic on it, you need a format that supports the numbers that the arithmetic will generate. What range of numbers is that? Are they all integers? Are they signed?

Comment: If you will not do arithmetic on it, is it just a string of symbols, whether decimal digits, binary bits, or something else? If it is just a string of symbols, is all you need an array of bits to record those symbols?

Comment: ETH -> ethereum token. It's a monetary balance that has up to 18 decimal places. Also some tokens (also monetary balances) have same amount of places but the amounts can easily reach the billions in some cases.

I will do arithmetic on it.